# Embeddable Container in Jboss 6.0.0.Final

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, ejb-3.1, jboss6.x

I'm trying develop unit tests for EJB 3.1 session beans, and I can't find anything definitive as to whether or not this is supported/included.

- Has anyone had success using this?
- Which jars are needed for the embeddable container?
- Configuration with Ant?